# What does this C declaration int *(*table())[10] do?

Tags: c

I am trying to write C code to create a two-dimensional array of function pointers, where every function takes no arguments and returns `int`.
I have already tried this code:

```
int *(*table())[10];
```

but it didn't work. Do you have any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can "decode" such definitions here: [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/). This not only helps while reading code but also when trying to find correct definition.

Comment: Please take care to select a title that really matches your question.

Comment: C don't have two-dimensional arrays (only arrays of arrays, arrays of pointers, arrays of scalars, arrays of aggregates)

Comment: @Gerhardh Please don't change the question after I have taken time to answer it. There happens to be 2 questions. I've now updated my answer to answer both of them. I did a rollback of your edit.

Comment: @Lundin I somehow missed your answer. Sorry.

Comment: Well, the question "how to declare a 2D array of function pointers" is admittedly a far more useful question than "how to interpret this gibberish" :)

Comment: There is a cool site which "translates" complicated C declarations https://cdecl.org/ . In this case the translation is "*declare table as function returning pointer to array 10 of pointer to int*".

Answer (score 3):

C declarations are built such that typing the declarators as an expression yields the type. So, let's assume we already have such a 2D array `a`. How to get `int` out of it?

1. Index once, getting a 1D array: `a[10]`.
2. Index again, getting a pointer to function: `a[10][10]`
3. Dereference the pointer, getting a function: `*a[10][10]`
4. Call the function, getting an `int`: `(*a[10][10])()`

So the final declaration is:

```
int (*a[10][10])(void);
```

Of course, as usual, it's much easier with `typedef`s:

```
typedef int Fun(void);
typedef Fun *FunPtr;

FunPtr a[10][10];
```

Comment: @Gerhardh Indeed, amended. Thanks. I'm primarily a C++ dev, so I tend to forget about that.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya The definition in the question is not the solution but where he is stuck. That is the reason for the question. "i am trying to write C code that create two dimensional array of function pointer's...."

Comment: @Gerhardh, I see. Thanks, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: There's actually 2 questions so indeed a bit confusing. The main question being "What does this C declaration int *(*table())[10] do?" and then "Do you have any idea how can I fix it?". This answer answers the latter question. I have posted an answer answering the former one.

Comment: Side-note regarding style: I prefer to use `typedef int Fun (void)` and then `Fun*` to get a function pointer. That makes the typedef consistent with the rest of C, and also saves you from getting the "Hungarian notation creeps" (such as using `LPWORD` instead of of `uint32_t*`).

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, I wouldn't use `FunPtr` in normal code. But it's useful here to make the final declaration as straightforward as reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding what the declaration you came up with does, that's a pretty icky declaration. You can unwind it with the [clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Basically the `table()` part means there's a a function. The `()` is obsolete C, meaning a function taking any parameter. You should be using `(void)` instead.

The `int* (* ... ) [10]` part means that you have a function returning an array pointer to an array `int* [10]`. Such an array pointer is normally declared as  `int* (*name)[10]` when written outside a function return value.

So you have a function declaration, of a function returning an array pointer, to an array of 10 int*, the function is taking an obsolete style parameter list.

You can understand it better with this example:

```
typedef int* (*arrptr)[10]; // to illustrate, typedef an array pointer int* (*)[10]

typedef arrptr func_t (void); // typedef a function type returning said array pointer

void func (func_t* x){}
// dummy function to demonstrate type compatibility, funct_t* is a function pointer 


int *(*table(void))[10]; // function declaration

int main (void)
{

  func(table); // table is of same type as the function pointer func_t*

  return 0;
}

int *(*table(void))[10]
{
  return 0;
}
```

Please note that hiding arrays and pointers behind typedefs is normally bad practice.

---

Regarding how to get an array of function pointers, it is way more straight-forward than interpreting the above gibberish.

- `int* func (void)` This is a function.
- `int* (*func) (void)` This is a function pointer to such a function.
- `int* (*func[10][10]) (void)` This is a 2D array of function pointers.

Or preferably:

- `typedef int* func_t (void)` This is a function type.
- `func_t* fptr` This is a function pointer to such a function.
- `func_t* fptr[10][10]` This is a 2D array of function pointers.

Comment: Isn't `int* [10]` array of pointers instead of pointer to array? What do you mean by saying `array pointer` ?

Comment: @snr Indeed, hence the `...`. When returning an array pointer from a function you can't write `int* (*)[10] myfunction ()` because the C syntax is dysfunctional. It is actually impossible to write C functions returning arrays. Writing this without typedefs is the road to madness even for seasoned C programmers.

Comment: `()` is not obsolete in C.  It can be used in this context to point to functions regardless of their parameter list.

Comment: @M.M "6.11.6 Function declarators.
The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter type declarators) is an obsolescent feature." Been like that since C99 iirc.

Comment: @Lundin `func(table)` is warned by compiler such that _parameter type mismatch: incompatible function return types `arrptr` and `int *[10]`_

Comment: @snr Hmm, I get no warnings with this exact code. There should be no `int* [10]` either.

Comment: @Lundin you can glance at the image sir --> https://i.imgur.com/oMrhbRs.gif

Comment: @snr I don't doubt you but the question is why there's a different result on your compiler. Which compiler, version and options are you using?

Comment: @Lundin CLion last version, `set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra")`

Comment: @snr All right, I found some incorrect things in my answer, this isn't a function pointer but a function declaration. I'll update.

Comment: @Lundin ok, sir. One of the weak part of me is function pointers which can be really confusing sometimes. I'm looking forward your update.

Comment: @snr Well, I couldn't find any problems with the code though, apart from the missing function definition which I've added now. Compiles clean with latest version of gcc, clang and icc. Are you sure you aren't compiling as C++ or something?

Comment: @Lundin In my opinion, the spiral rule should not be cited here. Because the correct solution suggested by Angew in his answer cannot be read properly with the Spiral rule.